# Fast filtering of listBox items wpf?

Tags: wpf

I have  a ListBox with atleast 1000 items each of class say "Data" that has a "Name" property.
I also have a text box above the listbox used for filtering items in the listbox based on your input text. How do I go about performing a fast lookup of items in the listbox.

I tried doing something like this:
In the textBox_textChanged event, I get the text, and use the 
CollectionViewSource class to filter out items but this results in a very jerky ui. ( I am filtering out items by taking the Name property on my Data class and doing a string.Contains() call)

Are there ways to speed up the search?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975084/how-can-i-execute-wpf-filters-on-a-background-thread

Comment: Do you get any better performance by binding to a ListCollectionView using the Filter property to filter your set?

Answer (score 0):

I use LINQ to filter thousands with great response time.

FTSwordFilter is the filter.  When it is changed I call NotifgyPropertyChanged on filtered list.

```
return FTSwords.Where(ftsWrd => ftsWrd.StemStartsWith(FTSwordFilter));

public Boolean StemStartsWith(string stemStart)
    {
        return (WordStem).StartsWith(stemStart);
    }
```

Just replace StartsWith with Contains

I also have an option for fuzzy filtering using DamerauLevenshteinDistance

I was doing it on a background task but it is fast enough that I moved it to the foreground.

I added a 2/10 second delay to allow for entering multiple characters.